# best way to calculate the percentage from SQL/JAVA

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a query as below:

```
SELECT  dbo.tablename.part_number,
        DATEPART(year, dbo.tablename_test.test_date_time) as year,
        DATEPART(month, dbo.tablename_test.test_date_time) as month,
        COUNT(dbo.tablename_test.overall_pass) AS Count,
        dbo.tablename_test.overall_pass 
FROM dbo.tablename_test 
    INNER JOIN dbo.tablename 
        ON dbo.tablename_test.tablename_id = dbo.tablename.tablename_id 
WHERE dbo.tablename_test.test_date_time BETWEEN '2003-01-01' AND '2013-06-01' 
AND (dbo.tablename_test.resolution_code IS NULL 
    OR dbo.tablename_test.resolution_code = 'None') 
AND dbo.tablename_test.operator IN ('Arlene Haselhorst','Trang Luong','Elena Viloria')
GROUP BY DATEPART(year, dbo.tablename_test.test_date_time),
         DATEPART(month, dbo.tablename_test.test_date_time),
         dbo.tablename.part_number,
         dbo.tablename_test.overall_pass 
ORDER BY  DATEPART(year, dbo.tablename_test.test_date_time),
          dbo.tablename.part_number,
          dbo.tablename_test.overall_pass
```

The output of this query is:

```
#   part_number year    month   count   overall_pass
#1  700-0376    2003    8        2        0
#2  700-0376    2003    11       1        0
#3  700-0376    2003    8        59       1
#4  700-0376    2003    10       34       1
#5  700-0376    2003    11       63       1
#6  700-0376    2004    2        12       0
#7  700-0376    2004    3         3       0
#8  700-0376    2004    5        13       0
#9  700-0376    2004    7        5        0
#10 700-0376    2004    11       3        0
#11 700-0376    2004    2       139       1
#12 700-0376    2004    3       150       1
#13 700-0376    2004    5       287       1
#.    .            .     .       .        .
#.    .            .     .       .        .
```

The result show data for only one partnumber. There are more than one partnumber. 
I need to find the percentage of the value for overall pass for each partnumber,year,month

How can I do this in SQL. What would be best approach to do this in JAVA. I need to have data like :

```
partnumber year month overallpass percentage
700-0376   2003  8      1          95.72
700-0376   2003  11     1          98.43
700-0376   2003  10     1          100.00
700-0376   2004  2      1          92.05
 .           .    .     .            .
 .           .    .     .            .
```

the percentage is calculated as count value `(59)/61(59+2)*100=95.72`. I need to do this for all partnumber for same year and month.

I have to fetch the data from the database and plot it on graph using google chart. What could be best approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

if I have interpreted the question OK, you need a case expression inside the count when counting passes (eg to get 59) but not do this for the divisor (to get 61) and you don't want overall pass in the group by

```
SELECT
      dbo.tablename.part_number
    , DATEPART(YEAR, dbo.tablename_test.test_date_time)                          AS year
    , DATEPART(MONTH, dbo.tablename_test.test_date_time)                         AS month
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN overall_pass = 1 THEN dbo.tablename_test.overall_pass END) AS Count_Passes
    , COUNT(dbo.tablename_test.overall_pass)                                     AS Count_All
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN overall_pass = 1 THEN dbo.tablename_test.overall_pass END)
      / COUNT(dbo.tablename_test.overall_pass)                                   AS Count_Percent
FROM dbo.tablename_test
      INNER JOIN dbo.tablename
                  ON dbo.tablename_test.tablename_id = dbo.tablename.tablename_id
WHERE dbo.tablename_test.test_date_time BETWEEN '2003-01-01' AND '2013-06-01'
      AND (dbo.tablename_test.resolution_code IS NULL
      OR dbo.tablename_test.resolution_code = 'None')
      AND dbo.tablename_test.operator IN ('Arlene Haselhorst', 'Trang Luong', 'Elena Viloria')
GROUP BY
      DATEPART(YEAR, dbo.tablename_test.test_date_time)
    , DATEPART(MONTH, dbo.tablename_test.test_date_time)
    , dbo.tablename.part_number
ORDER BY
      dbo.tablename.part_number
      , DATEPART(YEAR, dbo.tablename_test.test_date_time)
      , DATEPART(MONTH, dbo.tablename_test.test_date_time)
```

Comment: Grouping by a column used in an aggregate function won't work.  Besides the problems in the original query.

Comment: I need the percentage value of a part_number for a year,month whose overall_pass=1 and overall_pass=0. For instance:  there may be two or one value/values of part_number with same year and same month but different overall_pass and count. I need to find percentage of pass and fail for those value and similarly for rest of data. Hope I am clear with what I expect my data to look like.

Comment: it wasn't my intention to have overall_pass in the group by - as indicated by the opening statement - the error is corrected - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you shouldn't use the [inclusive upper bound of `BETWEEN` with positive contiguous-range types](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) (of which date/time/timestamps are a subset), *especially* if dealing with date/time/timestamps in SQL Server.  As it stands, you're including just the first day of June (for the last year), which I find rather suspect.

Additionally, the use of functions on your in-table data will invalidate the use of indices, making queries over large result sets slow.  You want a range table, something that looks like this:

```
range_start    range_end     year   month
==========================================
'2003-01-01'   '2003-02-01'  2003   1
'2003-02-01'   '2003-03-01'  2003   2
..............
'2013-05-01'   '2013-06-01'  2013   5
```

If you have a calendar table, you should be able to use the data there.  Otherwise, you can generate one trivially with a recursive CTE:

```
WITH Calendar_Range AS (SELECT d AS range_start, DATEADD(month, 1, d) AS range_end,
                               DATEPART(year, d) AS year, DATEPART(month, d) AS month
                        FROM (VALUES(CAST('20030101' AS DATE))) t(d)
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT range_end AS range_start, DATEADD(month, 1, range_end) AS range_end,
                               DATEPART(year, range_end) AS year, DATEPART(month, range_end) AS month
                        FROM Calendar_Range
                        WHERE range_end < CAST('20130601' AS DATE))
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle Demonstration](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/36706/0)</kbd>

Now, what's the difference between `COUNT(*)` and `COUNT(<expression>)`?  The latter (second) will ignore (not count) null rows.  We can use this with a simple join condition to not count rows... something like the following

```
SELECT COUNT(p.didPass)
FROM tablename_test
LEFT JOIN (VALUES(1)) p(didPass)
       ON p.didPass = tablename_test.overall_pass
```

...which is essentially the equivalent of `CASE`-counting rows (although the optimizer *may* be able to better optimize this)

The resulting query can then look like this:

```
WITH Calendar_Range AS (SELECT d AS range_start, DATEADD(month, 1, d) AS range_end,
                               DATEPART(year, d) AS year, DATEPART(month, d) AS month
                        FROM (VALUES(CAST('20030101' AS DATE))) t(d)
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT range_end AS range_start, DATEADD(month, 1, range_end) AS range_end,
                               DATEPART(year, range_end) AS year, DATEPART(month, range_end) AS month
                        FROM Calendar_Range
                        WHERE range_end < CAST('20130601' AS DATE))

SELECT Calendar_Range.year, Calendar_Range.month, Part.part_number, 
       100.0 * COUNT(Pass.didPass) / COUNT(*) AS percentage
FROM dbo.tablename Part
JOIN dbo.tablename_test Test
  ON Test.tablename_id = Part.tablename_id
     AND Test.operator IN('Arlene Haselhorst','Trang Luong','Elena Viloria')
     AND (Test.resolution_code IS NULL OR Test.resolution_code = 'None')
JOIN Calendar_Range
  ON Test.test_date_time >= Calendar_Range.range_start
     AND Test.test_date_time < Calendar_Range.range_end
LEFT JOIN (VALUES(1)) Pass(didPass)
       ON Pass.didPass = Test.overall_pass
GROUP BY Calendar_Range.year, Calendar_Range.month, Part.part_number
ORDER BY Calendar_Range.year, Calendar_Range.month, Part.part_number
```

(untested, as no sample starting data was provided)

I eliminated `overall_pass` from the final result set, as a constant column doesn't really tell you anything (when the value is known).  To avoid confusion, I matched the ordering of columns in the `SELECT` to the `ORDER BY` (I also switched around the columns in the `GROUP BY`, but this doesn't actually change the results).  I adjusted the order of operations, and used a floating point value, for calculating `percentage`, or you would have ended up with integer division (ie, get either `100` or `0`, but not anything in between).